# regular expression - parsing Twig Template

Tags: php, regex, twig

I need to get value of all "title" attributes in html page.
I use twig templates so source code can be like:

```
<a href="#" title="some {% func "smth" %} text">
```

I use this code to get title value:

```
/<[a-z]+[^>]*\s+(title|alt)\s*=\s*("[^"]*")/
```

but when title has `{% func "smth" %}` i get next string:

```
"some {% func "
```

how to get full string ?

**Update:** DOM isnt a solution because it will interprete the example link above as

```
<a href="#" title="some {% func " smth text></a>
```

Comment: a lot of parsing html with regex questions these days...

Comment: Another [obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) in less than 12 hours. Is it Regex University graduation day again?

Comment: @Kerrek The Accepted Solution in that link is wrong. [Regex can parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491). Since we have parsers readily available you dont want to go through that effort though. Also, the OP isnt parsing HTML but Twig Templates which cannot be parsed by DOM.

Comment: @Gordon: fair enough - it all depends on what the OP means by "the code can be *like*". If it's exactly and always that particular snippet, then sure, go ahead and regex.

Comment: i do not parse html with regex, i just need to get value of html attribute, and i think it is what i can do with regex, only question how to get value from both title="title" and title="title {% func "val" %}"

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
/<[a-z]+[^>]*\s+(title|alt)\s*=\s*(".*")/
```

The problem was that the `[^"]` blocks any quotes, such as `"smth"`. The closing `"` in your regex will find the end of your string just fine.

Comment: But as it has been said quite clearly and forcibly above, you might not want to use to regex to parse HTML.